# Apache POI Currency Data Format

Tags: java, apache-poi

I try to convert numbers into european currency style with Apache POI

```
HSSFDataFormat cf = workbook.createDataFormat();
currencyCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
currencyCellStyle.setDataFormat(cf.getFormat("#.###,#0"));
```

I have for example the number 2400 and 2.4

What I want is 2400,00 and 2,40 . 
But POI gives me 2400,0 and 2,40.
When I try to change it to

```
currencyCellStyle.setDataFormat(cf.getFormat("#.###,00"));
```

I get the result 2400,00 and 2,400.
Thats also not what I want.

Is there a possibility to get both values correct?

Thx and Greetings

Comment: I think you need to set the format string to be US/UK style, then open the file in a copy of Excel in a European Locale and it'll render as you expect. Did you try that?

Comment: thx that works partly. The comma and the point are set in european style when using "#,###.#0" which is changed when opening in excel to 2.400,0 . But I only get one zero after the comma. The input number is 2400.

Comment: What happens if you create a new file in Excel, style it how you want, then load it in Apache POI and read the format string, what do you see there?

Comment: perfect. I created a excel file and set the style of a cell to currency with 2 digits. Then I read the file with apache poi and read the cell style with cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString() and it returned '#,##0.00\ _€'  So I added this format as my format string. Thus I had cf.getFormat("#,##0.00\\ _€") And that is working perfectly. Never seen this formatting with the euro symbol and the underscore somewhere else.

Comment: Best add it as an answer, so everyone knows it's solved!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally Gagravarr gave the right tips to solve this question.

The final solution is:

```
HSSFDataFormat cf = workbook.createDataFormat();
currencyCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
currencyCellStyle.setDataFormat(cf.getFormat("#,##0.00\\ _€"));
```

The solution came up after creating an excel file manually. 
Then read it in by Apache Poi and
extracting the format string with

```
 cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString()
```

The result was #,##0.00\ _€

So I used this format in the upper code snippet, which gave the correct result.

Thx

Comment: Hi, I have your same problem. Reading this page I got my format string, set that to the currencyCellStyle variable but I don't know how to use it to read the correct value. cell.getNumericCellValue()? cell.getStringCellValue()? Can you please explain how you read the cell value using the dataformat you just set?
Thank you.

Comment: I also would like to add that the cells I need to read are both numbers and calculated ones, so there are formulas too to be evaluated. I have a HSSFFormulaEvaluator to evaluate them, but the result is still inconsistent with what Excel shows as result (I'm talking about precision and rounding).

Comment: hi, sorry I think I cant help you, because I dont read the cell values. I`m just writing with setCellValue. For Example cell.setCellStyle(currencyCellStyle) and cell.setCellValue(value)

Comment: Good tips.
In my case `# ##0,00 €;- # ##0,00 €;- €` was `#,##0.00\ "€";\-\ #,##0.00\ "€";\-\ "€"` so in Java it was `getFormat("#,##0.00\\ \"€\";\\-\\ #,##0.00\\ \"€\";\\-\\ \"€\"")`

Answer (score 3):

An update to the above approach:
After manually creating excel file with the required currency formatting, the format string can be obtained under the "Custom" category (in Format Cell dialog). That way we need not read the excel via poi to get this string.

Answer (score 2):

Cannot write a Comment due my reputation. But if you need Integer € with dots each 3rd Number (e.g. 24.000.123 €) the Pattern is:

```
#,##0\ "€";\-#,##0\ "€"
```

So set format:

```
cell.getCellStyle().setDataFormat(cf.getFormat("#,##0\\ \"€\";\\-#,##0\\ \"€\""));
```

Hope this will help some out.