# How to get currency code from Excel using Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm using POI to parse Excel file and reg. expression to detect currency in `NumericCellValue`. I have 2 fields in Excel file with 2 difference currencies (100$ and 100€) and I need to get their currency code ("USD", "EUR").

```java
case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC: {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(currencyFilter);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(dataFormat);
    if (m.find()) {
         BigDecimal aCurrency = currentCell.getNumericCellValue();
         //I need to pass my currency code from cell field to money instance
         Money money = new Money(aCurrency, "USD");
    }
}
```

Comment: `XSSFCellStyle currency=cell.getCellStyle();
System.out.println(currency.getDataFormatString());` this should return you the format as string. you can also get it as short with `.getDataFormat()`. after this you can compare with the defined value

Comment: it return all field format as [$$-409]#,##0.00;[RED]\-[$$-409]#,##0.00 but how can i translate this to get only  currency code

Comment: for me dollar string is: [$$-409]#,##0.00 while euro is: _-* #,##0.00 [$€-1]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$€-1]_-;_-* "-"?? [$€-1]_-;_-@_- . as you can see, dollar only contains dollar sign while euro contains euro and dollar sign. now you can check if the string contains these characters. there are predefined shorts you can also compare with. here is a list https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html

Comment: another hint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838495/apache-poi-currency-data-format

Comment: Did you try using `DataFormatter`?

Comment: I added if(dataFormat.contains("$$")){
 currencyCode = "USD";} It works, I try DataFormatter but i didnt find a way how to get only currencyCode. getDefaultFormat return same as getDataFormatString

Comment: Run `DataFormatter.formatCellValue` on the cell, then check what symbol comes back on the formatted string

Comment: But what is the difference formatCellValue return String with your cell format of your field. With getDataFormatString i getting the same format and Im just checking if this line has currency symbols I assigning to string corresponding currency code. The idea was how can I get currency code directly from field and just passing it to string without any if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String currencyCode = "";
if (dataFormat.contains("$$")) {
    currencyCode = "USD";
}
else if (dataFormat.contains("$€")) {
    currencyCode = "EUR";
}
moneyCurrency = new Money(bd, currencyCode);
```